# Mini HDMI female - is one pin supposed to be shorter?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pinout, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with Mini HDMI output. I acts kinda weirdly - it does work with a TV with HDMI input, but when plugged into a monitor with DVI input (with an appropriate HDMI>DVI cable) it makes the monitor turn off (yes, you're reading that right - Pi is still running, but the monitor turns off and can't be turned back on until I unplug the Pi, as if it was shorting something). I noticed that one of the pins in the female HDMI connector of the Pi is shorter than others - 18th, to be specific. Is it supposed to be that way, or do I have a defective unit? I wasn't able to find any high resolution image of the connector to be able to determine that by myself, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Variable lengths of contacts is common for hot-plug / hotswap interfaces (so that things are connected in the correct order).

Comment: that is the +5V pin ... http://pinoutguide.com/PortableDevices/mini_hdmi_pinout.shtml

Comment: try leaving everything connected. just power down the RPi